# AndroidManifest.xml rewrites itself after adding code

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

When I manually add code to AndroidManifest.xml with the Eclipse 4.2.1 xml editor, the code will work for awhile but randomly the code I added such as permissions will disappear, breaking the app. Am I editing the manifest wrong? I do not use the GUI when adding permissions and the like. I do not delete or modify the file when the code goes missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you editing the correct AndroidManifest.xml? There's one in the base folder of your project, which is the one you're supposed to edit, and there's one in the bin folder, editing which will result in the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Turns out I must have opened the manifest in the bin folder at one point and kept using the opened tab!

Comment: The files you can find in gen and bin folders MUST never be edited, they are generated when you update the src and/or drawable folders.
In order to avoid this kind of mistake, you shoud ask Eclipse to hide them using the Package Explorer filters.
Check the "Name filter patterns" and set it to "bin,gen" then click "Ok" ;)